# How can I match names and numbers and plug the numbers into x,y 2D table in Excel/Mac Numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A, there are 8 last names. Column B has a number for each name. Column C list the same people, but with first and last names. Column D has a number for each name. How can I match column C to column A, take the numbers attached to the name and input them into INDEX(B2:K11, MATCH(L3, B1:K1,0), MATCH(L2, A2:A11,0)) function which is connected to the table on Sheet 2 and then take the number from L4 and put it into column E of Sheet 1?

Ex.
[image: Screenshot of Sheet 1]

The names in column A are in the correct order and won't change. For Mike Ingram, 4 is L2 and 5 is L3. L4 will equal 33(not shown). 33 will show in cell E3 on Sheet 1.

I'm using Numbers, but most Excel functions work. This is beyond my elementary understanding of spreadsheet programs, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that there won't be a Barabara Beck or a Sarah Johnson?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Only 8 people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here for the L2 and L3 formulas:

I also added an example for L4 (which is different to your L4) to show how to refer to another table on the same sheet.

The reference  works similarly for a second table on another sheet, and Numbers will assist you when you select the reference inside the formulae.

If you want to refer to the names row by row, L2 can be simplified with a direct cell reference (see cells E4 and E5 as examples)

I am confident you can adjust your L4 accordingly.

Assumption is that the family name is the second part of the name string after the [space] (and no duplicates in column A and column C)

You may also need to adjust ; with , due to regional settings if not done automatically by Numbers.

Edit 2: use column A as reference

```
=INDEX(Table 2::A$1:E$6;B8;XLOOKUP(REGEX(A8);C$1:C$8;D$1:D$8;0;2;1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Anonymous, thanks for replying. The first row works, I'm getting the correct number for Wells in E1. I'm running into an issue with the rest of the list. When I go to A2, column C is just going to the next in the list, instead of matching surnames. For example, when I click on A2, C5 is also highlighted instead of C6. Also, I didn't use real names and didn't think about this; how would I use " " for two or three spaces for someone with a separated surname like De Luca? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look here how to use TEXTAFTER: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/functions/ffa1190ffee5/12.1/web/1.0 currently it checks out the first occurrence of the “ “.

Comment: I explained it poorly; E1=D4, E2=C3, E3=D5, E4=E4, E5=E4, E6=B6, E7=E3, E8=D2. I should really have the list in column E right after column A.

Comment: See Edit 2 for using column A as reference. Note: regex(A1) does not consider to position of “Wells”, i.e. both “Barbara Wells” or “Wells Barbara” (or “abc Wells xyz”) would be considered the same. If you want to compare a substring after a space etc., you may specify the regex, e.g.: ```=XLOOKUP(REGEX("\w+ "&B11);C$1:C$8;D$1:D$8;0;2;1)``` or try with wildcards: ```=INDEX(Table 2::A$1:E$6;B8;XLOOKUP("* "&A8;C$1:C$8;D$1:D$8;0;2;1))```

Comment: It works! I had to change B8 and (A8) to B1 and (A1). Thank you so much for your help.